# Save data from text area to file

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure this is noobish but I am not  JS guy. I'm just helping someone out with a simple form.

I have a text area where some custom XML data is written based on input from the user. It displays in the readonly text area so they can see what they are creating but I also have a button that will download it to the correct file name so they can upload it to another system we support.

I used the code [here](http://cssdeck.com/labs/7bx7mmcm) and modified for my own situation.

Works flawlessly in Chrome but nothing happens at all in Firefox (or IE but I don't particularly care a great deal about that one). Nothing at all appears in the console/log in FF.

Here's the js

```
   function saveTextAsFile()
{


    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("XMLTextArea").value;
        var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/plain'});
        var fileNameToSaveAs = "MyFile.xml";

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.URL != null)
    {
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event)
{
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

And relevant HTML

```
<textarea readonly id= 'XMLTextArea' cols='100' rows='40' > BLAH </textarea>

<button onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save XML File</button>
```

Comment: "I also have a button that will download it to the correct file name so they can upload it to another system we support." Anyway you could let them review it, and then directly upload it into the secondary system without the manual download/upload process? Sounds absolutely ripe for automation

Comment: `document.createElement(\"a\")` needs to be  `document.createElement("a")` - Not sure what the `window.URL` test is for,  it exists in FF & Chrome, may as well just go the appendChild route regardless.

Comment: @ADyson LOL no kidding - dont even get me started on why this was never done in the first place. Expecting end users to know what an XML file is and how to create one is ridiculous but they won't spend the time to make the interface on the main system...

Comment: @AlexK. Thank you - the "\" were a copy/paste error it is just "a" in the real code. I will try without the test and see, thanks

Comment: @Brodie so the current manual upload process isn't something you could emulate with an automated process then? Even without a proper API? That's very annoying!

Comment: @ADyson No, after the XML file is created it needs to be packaged a specific way and then uploaded to a completely different server where the main application is. Yes it absolutely could be done easily, but I am not a part of the team that developed it, just a part of the team that supports it. This is a massive org and everything is compartmentalized. They didn't see the need to spend the dev hours to make this interface that took me all of four hours yesterday....<can you tell I'm annoyed?>

Comment: @AlexK. Your comment led me to the answer - thank you. I removed the test left the code in the else block. Working great in both browsers. If you turn that into an answer I'll accept it